# Reading integers from console in C#

Tags: c#

Please look at the following C++ code and help me to do the same in c#

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 cout<<"Enter a["<<i<<"]=";
 cin>>a[i];
}
```

I tried to implement the same loop in C# for taking integer input but it ended with exception like following

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
a[i]=Int32.Parse(Cosole.Read());
}
```

Can anyone help me to implement that loop in C#? The parse work one time but it doesn't work inside loop. Whats the problem?

Comment: What is the type of `a` in your C++ program?

Comment: Also, what is the exception? And have you considered `Console.ReadLine()` and `Int32.TryParse` instead?

Comment: a is an integer array. It fails to take input and shows windows explorer stopped unexpectedly. i.e. run time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only reads the next character from the standard input stream, which will not work if you want to read `32` as an integer. You better use [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    int value;
    if (Int32.TryParse(line, out value))
    {
       a[i] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        // cannot parse it as an integer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a[{0}]=",i);
    a[i]=Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Pleace check [this](http://dotnetfiddle.net/1aHUVW) fiddle.

Comment: Please give me few seconds to provide you a fiddle to see that works. Thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 0):

if I ve understood you correct...

```
for(...)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enter a {0}"),i);
    a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
}
```

Smth like that...

Comment: Btw you can flag a mod at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11767668/632951 and ask him to merge that question into this account.

Comment: you mean, merge two accounts to one? It would be great for me

Comment: Yes merge two accounts into one so that all the posts are merged into one account. Click on the "flag" link, click "other", then type in the message to the moderator.