# How do i add a value from a Console.ReadLine into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to read a float value from the user and store that value in an array, so that i can then add it all and divide it by the amount of inputs that the user has given me, once they type in a value bellow 0.

```
using System;

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

 float [] tt;
    
 int ct = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i>-1; i++); {

   float id = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


   if (id > -1) {
     ct++;
   } else {
     Console.WriteLine(id/ct);
   }


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your for loop will execute infinitely. what is correct exit condition for `for loop`

Comment: Similar enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040525/reading-integers-from-console-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float sum = 0;
        int ct = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            float id = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (id > -1)
            {
                sum += id;
                ct++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sum / ct);
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

A better code is written as follows, and more checks are added here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<double>();
        while (true)
        {
            var line = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!double.TryParse(line, out var number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Can't parse number: {line}");
                return;
            }

            if (number < 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            list.Add(number);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The average is: " + list.Average());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've build and test the code. The loop will never stop.
I encountered a problem here. Do not change the code as much as possible to make it easier for the person asking the question to understand, or use the best way of writing...
List<double> Average is enough to finish the job, but I don't think he/she has learned LINQ.

Comment: ok, I have updated the answer... now the loop will stop when the user input an negative(<=-1) number, thank you~